# Organization and Group relation

Tags: java, liferay

Hi can someone pleas tell me how can i get organization group id in liferay 6.2 database?

I am in need to create sql query in database, Where are the organization and group releations stored

I checked Groups_Orgs table but this is empty, in ui there is lots of sites white organisations.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using? In Liferay 6.2 and onwards, there is no hard and fast rule over creation of organization, you can directly create site(s) / group(s).

Comment: 6.2. I am in need to create sql query in database, Where are the organization and group releations stored

Comment: You could get group information by organization-id. ie. by getting group record based on classpk on Group_ table (use organization-id as classPK). Using API method you can get Group information too. `GroupLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationGroup(long companyId, long organizationId)`

Comment: It worked thanks a lot

Comment: I am putting my comment as an answer.:)

Answer (score 1):

You could get group information by organization-id. ie. by getting group record based on classpk on Group_ table (use organization-id as classPK).

Using API method you can get Group information too. `GroupLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationGroup(long companyId, long organizationId)`